# Unity baked lighting blotchy and cubic

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

I've set every object in my scene to 'static' and the bake runs automatically, but the result is unusable: blotchy, blurred cubic lighting...
[image: front room blotchy baked lighting]

[image: upstairs hallway blotchy baked lighting]

Here are my lighting settings:
[image: lighting settings]

What am I doing wrong? I've tried changing the atlas size, the 'scale in lightmap' of the house object and various other settings, but can't seem to make the bake behave.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried going to Edit -> Project -> Quality settings, and playing around with the various options there?

Comment: I think I might have solved this, at least mostly. I found a forum post that suggested going to the individual meshes in the project's assets, inspecting each and checking the 'Generate Lightmap UVs' box for each mesh. The lighting could still use some work, but the black-and-white blurred cubes have gone!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the see how far from 0 the mesh is. I Had mine about -6000(y) and it had extremely blotchy/spotty lightmap results. I moved it much closer to 0(like -10y), re-baked and everything was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like UV overlap. For issues like this where some sections are bright white, red, or green (where they really shouldn't be), try

1. increasing the lightmap padding
2. toggling stitch seems on the render (mesh renderer or whatever it is for the object with white patches)
3. Play around with the other lighting settings
4. rebuild the UVs (A lot of forums will end with this, it can be quite manual. Luckily 1- 3 has always worked for me so far)